# Intellij jaxb xjc schema location for content assist

Tags: jaxb, intellij-idea, xsd, xml-namespaces, xjc

I'm using JAXB for generating code. Now I'm trying to add the XJC namespace to the custom `bindings.xjb` file, but IntelliJ Idea 12 won't find the namespace. The `xmlns:xjc="..."` row is marked red, and when I'm trying to use the "Fetch external resource" feature, it tells me `No XML at the location:  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc`. Where can I find the xsd file for the xjc namespace to activate content assist?

Heres the definition in my .xjb file:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
           xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: Did you try `JAXB_ROOT\lib\jaxb-xjc.src.zip\com\sun\tools\xjc\reader\xmlschema\bindinfo\xjc.xsd` file? You can unpack it and map to the namespace in `Settings` | `Schemas and DTDs`.

Comment: Good idea! Format your comment as answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB distribution has this file in

```
lib\jaxb-xjc.src.zip\com\sun\tools\xjc\reader\xmlschema\bindinfo\xjc.‌​xsd
```

unpack it and configure a namespace mapping in `Settings` | `Schemas and DTDs`.